# c code is inexplicably skipping lines

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile this small program for some reason the "printf("done")" line is not executing and I cannot figure out why. There was originally an if block before my print statement and that also was not executing. I tried running it through gdb and stepping through it. It found the line but it did not execute it. I am trying to compile it using gcc 4.7.2 and I'm using gedit 3.4.2 as my text editor.

Here is the command I'm using to compile it.

```
gcc teststuff.c -o test
```

And here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testmethod()
{

   int sign = 1;
   printf("hello\n");
   printf("%d\n",sign);


   printf("done");
}

main(void)
{
   testmethod();
   return 0;
}
```

Anybody have any ideas why it is skipping that part of the code? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `printf("done\n");`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a line break at the end.

```
printf("done\n");
```

Standard output is often line-buffered, that means that the data you write only gets flushed to the screen once you finish a line (unless you explicitly flush it, such as with `fflush()`).  However, it should be flushed when the program exits (but not necessarily *before* the program exits).

Also, depending on your shell, if a program writes data without a linebreak you might get your command prompt on top of the output:

```
my-computer ~/projects/my-program $ ./a.out
hello
1
donemy-computer ~/projects/my-program $
```

Comment: That also explains my if statement since I only had print statements inside of them and didn't have line breaks on them either.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your program finishes and ends before the `Done` line gets the chance to be printed to the console.

Console output is generally buffered. The string `"done"` stays in the buffer of `stdout` until the stream is flushed. You can do it manually by calling `fflush(stdout)`, or by adding `\n` to the end of the `"done"` string. Printing the end-of-line character causes console stream to empty the buffer onto the screen (unless you set a special output mode that lets `\n` to be buffered until an explicit flush).